# How to check are IIS and .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed in wix toolset?

Tags: iis, .net-core, installation, wix

How can I check are IIS and .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed in WiX Toolset Installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By detecting the registry key you will found the iis and .net core bundle are instlled or not:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components"
                     Value="W3SVC"
                     Variable="WebServer"/>

<ExePackage Id='IIS_WebServer'
            DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServer'
            PerMachine='yes'
            SourceFile='.\Resources\Dism.exe'
            InstallCondition='NOT WebServer'
            InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer'>
</ExePackage>
```

Below is the other iis components:

[Discover Installed Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components)

another way is you can use the Powershell to check the registry key:

```
$DotNETCoreUpdatesPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\.NET Core"
$DotNetCoreItems = Get-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Path $DotNETCoreUpdatesPath
$NotInstalled = $True
$DotNetCoreItems.GetSubKeyNames() | Where { $_ -Match "Microsoft .NET Core.*Windows Server Hosting" } | ForEach-Object {
    $NotInstalled = $False
    Write-Host "The host has installed $_"
}
If ($NotInstalled) {
    Write-Host "Can not find ASP.NET Core installed on the host"
}
```

[image]

[How to determine ASP.NET Core installation on a Windows Server by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-determine-ASPNET-512379b5)